# How to sample Pandas Dataframe with minimum distance between

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sample a Dataframe based on a given **Minimum Sample Interval** on the "timestamp" column. Every extracted value would be the closest extracted value to the last one that is at least **Minimum Sample Interval** larger than the last one. So what I mean is, for the table given below and **Minimum Sample Interval** = 0.2

```
          A     timestamp   
1  0.000000        0.1  
2  3.162278       0.15  
3  7.211103       0.45 
4  7.071068       0.55
```

Here, we would extract indexes:

- 1, no last value yet so why not
- Not 2, because it is only 0.05 larger than last value
- 3, because it is 0.35 larger than last value
- Not 4, because it is only 0.1 larger than last value.

I've found a way to do this with iterrows, but I would like to avoid iterating over it if possible.

Closest I can think of is integer dividing the timestamp column with floordiv as **interval** and finding the rows where **interval** value changes. but for a case like [0.01 , 0.21, 0.55, 0.61, 0.75, 0.41], I would be selecting 0.61 instead of 0.75, which is only 0.06 larger than 0.55, instead of 0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to compute the difference between each value and the next one:

```
sample = df[df['timestamp'].diff().fillna(1) > 0.2]
```

Output:

```
>>> sample
          A  timestamp
1  0.000000       0.10
3  7.211103       0.45
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my case at all.

Comment: Why not, @nihat? It produces your expected output, doesn't it? Will you please point out what's wrong with it?

Comment: With Your method, if we had 100 entries that all have  0.01 in between, you'd only choose the first one. I want there to be at least Minimum Sample Interval "between the selected entries".